# Kotlin not able to query users collection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a query in Firebase to get the value of an specific field in the USERS collection and I don't understand why ***.documents*** it's an Unresolved Reference. Any ideas?

```
fun getUserSpecialty() {
    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val specRef = usersCollectionRef.document(user)
    specRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        for (document in snapshot.documents) {  //.documents it's an Unresolved Reference 
            val data = document.data
            val userSpecialtyCode = data!![SPECIALTY_CODE] as String

            val loggedUserSpecialty = UserSpecialty(userSpecialtyCode)

            userSpecClass.add(loggedUserSpecialty)

            this.userSpecTxt?.text = userSpecialtyCode
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `snapshot` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot), and as you can see from the linked API documentation, it doesn't have a method called `getDocuments()` on it.

When you call `get()` on a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) as you are now, you get a **single document** as a DocumentSnapshot.  You do not get a QuerySnapshot like you do with queries that could return multiple documents.  You are probably confusing the two.